# Is there a way to change font style in TextEdit in qt?

Tags: qt

I am making an editor using qt , i can perform minimal operations using it like reading an existing file.

```
if(!file.isEmpty()) {
    QFile sfile(file);

    if(sfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        filename = file;
        QTextStream ts(&sfile);
        QString text = ts.readAll();

        sfile.close();

        ui->textEdit->setPlainText(text);
    }
}
```

now i want that all the text text that appears on the "text edit" should appear in a particular style, how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using the setFont function or the setStylesheet function like this example:

```
QFont font;
font.setFamily(QStringLiteral("Nyala"));
font.setPointSize(12);
font.setBold(false);
font.setItalic(false);
font.setWeight(50);
ui->textEdit->setFont(font);

ui->textEdit->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("font: 12pt \"Nyala\";"));
```

I recommend using Qt Designer or the build-in designer in Qt Creator

Comment: Or in c++11 even ui->textEdit->setFont(QFont("open sans", 12));